# ¿Como puedo hacer un redirect 301 correctamente?

Tags: .htaccess, redirección

tengo un problema al redirigir mi sitio web. Os cuento, he comprado el dominio https://www.viajardescubriendo.es para hacer una redirección 301 a mi dominio principal https://www.viajardescubriendo.com. Mi hosting primero me dijo que aparque el dominio y luego vaya a la carpeta .htaccess de mi dominio principal (https://www.viajardescubriendo.com) y ponga esta información: `RedirectMatch 301 (. *) https://www.viajardescubriendo.com/`. También probé esto:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine en
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https://www.viajardescubriendo.com/$1 [R = 301, L]
</IfModule>
```

El primero se queda mi sitio web se queda en blanco y el segundo solo me redirige el dominio principal... Los artículos no. Es decir que un .es/lo-que-sea no se redirige a .com/lo-que-sea. Sé que estoy haciendo algo mal. Pero no sé qué ... espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias :)

[image: Probema 1]

[image: Problema 2]

Comment: Creo que la expresión regular la tienes mal. Seria `^(.*)`, sin espacios en blanco. Parece que has copiado/pegado mal esa información, por que la `H` te la ha convertido a mayúsculas y lo que hay entre corchetes también se ha separado.

Answer (score 0):

[@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia), tenias razón. El código correcto sería éste:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://viajardescubriendo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Me hace la redirección bien, pero solo se ve mi página principal, las demás sale esto:

[image: Mensaje de página no encontrada]

Comment: Esa ya es otra pregunta diferente. La redirección funciona, pero las urls amigables en el nuevo dominio aparentemente no.

Comment: @OscarGarcia y eso como hago para que funcione bien?

Comment: ¿Has instalado correctamente Wordpress en el nuevo alojamiento y has comprobado que todo funciona correctamente allí? La redirección te está funcionando, ahora lo que no te funiona, aparentemente, es wordpress.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya lo he conseguido hacer bien, me lo explicaron mal desde mi hosting... tenia que crear la web y desde hay meterme en el .htaccess y poner el código. Ya lo he conseguido hacer bien, menudo lío...Muchas gracias :D